# How to ask agents in a list (not an agentset) with repeats in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

Using NetLogo’s `rnd` extension to implement roulette-wheel selection, I can randomly select `num` agents, each with a probability proportional to its `weight`, and then ask each of those agents to execute `task`, like so:

`ask rnd:weighted-n-of num turtles [weight] [task]`

I would like to do the same thing but allow repeats in the agents randomly selected. The problem is that an agentset cannot contain the same turtle twice. As such, the analogous procedure that selects candidates with repeats, `rnd:weighted-n-of-with-repeats`, returns a list instead of an agentset. So this,

`ask rnd:weighted-n-of-with-repeats num turtles [weight] [task]`,

throws the error “ASK expected this input to be an agent or agentset, but got a list instead.”

So, I’m wondering: how can I ask all agents in the resulting list to execute a procedure, such as `task`?

Comment: separate the ideas so you create the list of agents and the loop through the list of agents with `foreach` and then `ask` each agent to do the task within the `foreach` loop